# Update multiple mysql rows with different values using php fast and quick (in around 100ms)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a table DIGITAL with columns 'VALUE' and 'ID'. I need to update the value as per the ID using php.

The values are in one array ($arr) and using for loop I am updating the 64 rows as follows:

```
  for($i=0;$i<64;$i++)
  {   
       $j=$i+1;
       $query="update DIGITAL set VALUE =$arr[$i] where ID='$j'";
       $exequery=mysqli_query($cn,$query);
  }
```

Updating 64 rows are taking around 400ms. I need to reduce the time to around 100ms.

Please give some tips to optimize my query and make it fast.

Comment: ID is primary key?

Comment: you could probably create a temporary table and insert those value id pairs then make an update join, (you'll have to benchmark them too to know)

Comment: save a ms not  quoting integers (ID)

Comment: @Bleach. yes ID is primary key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use case statement inside update and run loop over case statement.
Then Sample update query will look like Following

```
   UPDATE DIGITAL SET VALUE =  CASE  
                    WHEN ID= jValue1 THEN arrValue1
                    WHEN ID= jValue2 THEN arrValue2 
                    WHEN ID= jValue3 THEN arrValue3 
                    END ;
```

With PHP

```
    $query="UPDATE DIGITAL SET VALUE = CASE ";
    for($i=0;$i<64;$i++) { 
            $j=$i+1; $query .= " WHEN ID = '".$j."' THEN $arr[$i] "; 
    }
    $query .= 'END;'; 
    $exequery = mysqli_query($cn,$query);
```

Comment: @uddipana: I think with php you don't need to write 64 cases manually, With Loop, You can run loop like Shown in edited answer, I have updated answer that can be seen With PHP. I am not sure about php Syntax but you follow shown algorithm and check time taken

Answer (score 2):

You could try [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) - compile once, use many.  Most database systems use a fair amount of time interpreting statements, so this may improve your time.